# Adding days/date in current date using JPA query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to add 14 days more in current date using JPA.

```
SELECT 
    b.id as bookingID, b.account_id, b.campaign_id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(c.created, INTERVAL 14 DAY), '%m/%d/%Y') as campaignCreatedDate,
    DATE_FORMAT(c.program_start_date, '%m/%d/%Y')  as campaignPlannedStartDate
FROM
    booking b,
    account a,
    campaign c
WHERE
     b.stage IS NULL AND b.is_active = 1 AND a.is_active = 1 AND  c.is_active = 1 AND b.campaign_id = c.id AND  b.account_id = a.id;

 i am trying to covert above sql query into JPA like     

 @Query("select new com.xxx.campaign.model.TestRequest("
        + " b.id as bookingID, b.account.id,  accountOwner, "
        + " b.campaign.id, 
        + " c.created as campaignCreatedDate, "
        + " b.campaign.programStartDate as campaignPlannedStartDate) "
        + " FROM "
        + " Booking b "
        + " join b.account a "
        + " join b.campaign c "
        + " WHERE "
        + " b.stage IS NULL AND b.isActive = 1 AND b.account.isActive = 1 AND  b.campaign.isActive = 1")
public List<TestRequest> getTestDetails();
```

my SQL query adding 14 days more in current date
    for ex my current date is 01/01/2019
    i am getting output as 01/15/2019
    My question is , How can add 14 days through JPA query?

Comment: You might want to refer this example: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-or-substract-a-time-period-to-a-date-in-java-persistence-query-language-jpql/

Comment: @robot_alien Thanks to reply, I visited url you mentioned above. I think i can't achieve what i want through JPA. As mentioned "the bad news is that Java Persistence Query Language(JPQL) does not support such operations on dates yet."

Comment: Well Thank for help, I already did that through JAVA but i am looking through JPA.